# o count character entered through stdin first time it works for continuing the execution it is not readig the character

Tags: c

this code gives the output correctly for the first time but it is not reading the character for the second time execution scanf("%c"&op) is not reading the character for continuing the execution i tried with getchar(); and scanf(" %C",&op); but still it is not reading the input............................................................................

```
int main()
    {
        
        //declaring local variable
        char op;
        
        //do while for user interaction
        do
        {
        //function call
            count();
        
        //asking if user want to continue execution
        printf("\nDo you want to continue(Y/y):");
        scanf(" %c",&op);
        }while( op == 'Y' || op == 'y');
        return 0;
    }

    int count()
    {
       char ch;
       int word_count = 0, line_count = 0, char_count = 0;
    
       //asking user for the input
       puts("enter the sentence:");
    
       //Loop to fetch the input
    
            while( (ch =getchar()) != EOF)
            {
    
                //To count the number of characters
                char_count++;
    
                //If entered char is new line
                if (ch == '\n')
                {
                    //To count the number of lines in input
                    line_count++;
                }
    
                //To check if the entered input is space or tab or next line
                if(ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\n' )
                {
    
                    //Word count
                    word_count++;
    
                    //Get the char 
                    ch = getchar();
    
                    //To check if the enter char is space or tab or new line
                    if(ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\n' )
                    {
    
                        //If the entrered char is space or tab or new line
                        word_count--;
    
                    }
    
                    //Returing the character to input stream
                    ungetc(ch,stdin);
    
                }
         
            }
    
            //Printiong the number of char,word,line count
            printf("\n");
            printf("Line count\t: %d\n", line_count);
            printf("Word count\t: %d\n", word_count);
            printf("Character count\t: %d", char_count);
    
        return 0;
    
     }
```

Comment: @Suma_Km you haven't added any `exit condition` from `count()`. How will the program understand when to stop taking input from user?

Comment: Nothing breaks that loop in `count` as you posted it except `stdin` reaching EOF. At that point, what makes you think the `scanf` (which likewise reads from `stdin`) afterward back in `main` succeeds? If you bothered to check the result of `scanf`, it tells you how many parameters it parsed successfully. Do it, and you'll discover it is failing. And that's why verify our IO operations.

Comment: in function:  ,,,  regarding: `char ch;`  the value in `ch` is from that function: `getchar()`   However, note that `getchar()` returns a `int`, not a `char`, so `char ch;` needs to be modifed to  `int ch;`  otherwise, an EOF event will not be recognized

Answer (score 1):

For reading the character of the user's choice for continuation after you signaled `EOF` on the sentence input, you have to call `clearerr(stdin)` before the `scanf(" %c",&op)`.

> The `clearerr` function clears the end-of-ﬁle and error indicators for the stream …

Note that with your given `scanf(" %c",&op)`, the newline character entered after `y` will be read as part of the next sentence, increasing the line count by one. To avoid this for the case where the user enters only a single choice character, you could use `scanf(" %c%*c", &op)`. To handle also cases where the users enters more (e. g. `yes`), you could instead `getchar()` in a loop until `\n` or EOF.